# Failed to start program. Path or permissions wrong? in Qt

Tags: qt, qt-creator, qt-mobility

I have downloaded Qt Mobility Open source project. I had a set of demo apps. And when built it and started the App, I got this error:

> Failed to start program. Path or
>   permissions wrong?

Can someone tell me what this problem could be?

**UPDATE:**

The complete error is:

> Starting
>   /Users/xxxxx/Qt/qt-mobility-opensource-src-1.0.2/config.app/Contents/MacOS/config...
>   Failed to start program. Path or
>   permissions wrong?

I have include the ".pro" file contents:

```
TEMPLATE = app
TARGET = writemessage

QT += gui

include(../examples.pri)

CONFIG += mobility
MOBILITY = messaging
INCLUDEPATH += ../../src/messaging

HEADERS += \
    messagesender.h

SOURCES += \
    messagesender.cpp\
    main.cpp

symbian:TARGET.CAPABILITY = NetworkServices \
    LocalServices \
    ReadUserData \
    WriteUserData \
    UserEnvironment \
    ReadDeviceData \
    WriteDeviceData
```

Comment: Is it Qt Creator? Does it work if launched from command line? Also it could be useful if you posted your .pro file.

Comment: I did not try launching from command line. I am just learning it. I imported a sample Messaging App that came part of the open source project in to Qt creator and then I got this problem. I have updated my question with .pro file contents.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the problem you are facing here are either the user rights of the executable or a wrong build path.

First, try setting the build path under 'Projects' - 'General' - Build Directory to a correct path.

If that doesn't work, open the terminal, go to the build path and execute `./QtBuildProgram`

If that doesn't work, take a look at the user rights `ls -a ./QtBuildProgram`

Maybe the executable rights are not granted because you are running the Creator in another user mode as the terminal emulator.

Just to be sure, execute `sudo chmod u+x QtBuildProgram` and then execute the program from the command line by typing `./QtBuildProgram`

That should also allow you to run the program from the QtCreator again.

Answer (score 12):

I had the same issue in Windows. I found the answer. You need to check the "Working directory" parameter in "Run Settings" section.
I changed it to the same path as my build directory and it worked.

I was running QT as admin.

Answer (score 6):

My mac didn't have valgrind installed by default so I had to

```
brew install valgrind
```

Go back to QT Creator, and in Projects -> Run -> Valgrind Settings

Point the Valgrind executable to the brew installed version which you can
find by typing `which valgrind` on the command line.

Finally due to the bug report [here](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTCREATORBUG-18473) I realized that valgrind 3.13 has a bug and doesn't work, and valgrind 3.12 also doesn't work on macs, and mac os high sierra isn't supported by valgrind. So you're basically out of look until 3.14 comes around.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, it was because I have a 32-bit CPU and it was building 64-bit executables. I only figured this out after trying to run it from the command line though.

Answer (score 0):

Check your run settings and see if the exe path is existing and file is built there. If you are running windows 7 or windows 8, set the qtcreator executable's settings to "Run as administrator".

Answer (score 0):

Check your antivirus settings.

That was my issue.

Answer (score 0):

In my case this error was caused by a space at the start of "Working directory" path in "Run Settings".

Answer (score 0):

In my case, this error was due to antivirus that was blocking to run the exe file. I just turned off the Avira Shield for some time and it worked.

Answer (score -2):

In my case it was because I was missing these two lines of code at the top of the project. Make sure you have them without any space above :

```
#! /usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
```